# Another file's modules cannot be used

Tags: python, django

Another file's modules cannot be used.I have 2 filed of test1.py and test2.py .I want to use test2's class in test1. test2.py is

```
class Test2(object):
    def data(self, Test):
        self.user =user
```

test1.py is

```
class Test1(test2.Test2):
    def __init__(self):
        Test.__init__(self)
```

But when I run these codes,NameError: name 'test2' is not defined happens.In this time,I have no import statement.So I wrote codes `import test2 as te`in test1.py and I rewrote `class Test1(te.Test2):` but te is not defined  error happens.What is wrong in my code?How should I fix this?

Comment: Have you got any import statements you're not showing us? Have you got an `__init__.py` file so python knows it's a package?

Comment: https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/08/python-201-creating-modules-and-packages/ might help you.

Comment: @TomDalton First,i did not have any import statement.I have __init__.py file in test1&test2 directory

Answer (score 0):

Add `__init__.py` to the folder where you have test1.py and test2.py
That should work.

And replace code in test1.py with:

```
from test2 import Test2

class Test1(Test2):
    def __init__(self):
        Test.__init__(self)
```

Comment: thank you for  your answer.I already have it.In this case, should I write some import statement?

Answer (score 0):

I have created same files named test1.py and test2.py and copied your code into this files and add import which you said don't work for you and it works for me so maybe check if files are in same directory or if name of files are really test1 and test2